# Error handling cmdlet parameters?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I'm creating a new user on AD from user input off a form.

```
New-ADUser -Name $ADName -UserPrincipalName $UPN -SamAccountName $SAM -AccountPassword $Password -City $City -Country $Country `
           -Department $Department -Description $EmployeeNum -DisplayName $displayName -Division $Division -EmailAddress $Email -EmployeeNumber $EmployeeNum -GivenName $firstName `
           -Initials $MiddleInit -Office $CSCSuffix -OfficePhone $PhoneExt -PostalCode $Zipcode -State $State -StreetAddress $Street -Surname $LastName -Title $JobTitle`
           -OtherAttributes @{extensionAttribute1=$OfficePhone;extensionAttribute4=$Alias}  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

There's a bunch of parameters for the `New-ADUser` command and if one of those parameters is invalid then the whole `New-ADUser` command is thrown out.

#### Question

Is there anyway of ignoring bad parameters and continuing on to execute the parent command (whilst including all other valid parameters)?

#### Example

For example, `extensionAttribute4=$Alias`. `extensionAttribute4` cannot be null. If a user leaves `$Alias` blank then the command will break and not create a new user despite every other parameter being valid.

#### Remediation

I tried the `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` but that didn't work because that's just for the command itself. The only way I'd imagine I could make this work is by doing this:

```
New-ADUser -Name $ADName
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADName -Department $Department -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADName -OfficePhone $PhoneExt -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADName -OtherAttributes @{extensionAttribute1=$OfficePhone} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-ADUser -Identity $ADName -OtherAttributes @{extensionAttribute4=$Alias} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
....
```

I suppose I'd be fine doing this for error handling `-OtherAttributes` since it's a hash table but otherwise this isn't ideal.

Comment: Why don't you check your business logic before attempting to create the user through the cmdlets? It won't take much lines/time (currently, just a null check) to achieve what you want!

Answer (score 3):

You could supply a table of parameters to the cmdlet instead so that you can test for null before supplying the parameter. For example:

```
$parameters = @{}

# add your mandatory parameters
$parameters["SamAccountName"] = $SamAccountName 
# ...

if (-not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($department))
{
    $parameters["Department"] = $department
}

# ...

New-ADUser @parameters
```

Comment: Also known as splatting. This is the solution I would have offered.